# How to call custom jQuery slider in magento 2

Tags: magento2, jquery

Can anyone help me, I am new to Magento 2. I want to call custom jquery slider on home page on my local site. I have tried myself but not getting how to use it with requirejs-config.js. It will be very helpful if you explain from basic step by step.

Comment: you can use bootstrap slider , if you need to add bootstrap then I can help you out and with bootstrap you can use other features as well

Answer (score 4):

For example to call custom jQuery slider in home page of Magento you need to follow this steps

**Step 1:** Call you custom slider's **CSS** and **JS** in home page layout

Override **cms_index_index.xml** to your custom theme

> app/code/Vendor/theme/Magento_Cms/layout/cms_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <link src="Magento_Cms/js/myslider.js"/>
        <css src="Magento_Cms/css/myslider.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="index.home" template="Magento_Cms::slider.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Step 2:** Define your custom JS in **requirejs-config.js**

> app/code/Vendor/theme/Magento_Cms/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            mySlider: 'Magento_Cms/js/myslider'
        }
    },
    shim: {
        magnificPopup: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
};
```

**Step 3:** create phtml file which we called in layout for your slider html and js

> app/code/Vendor/theme/Magento_Cms/templates/slider.phtml

```
  <!-- Your Custom Slider HTML -->

  <script type="text/javascript">
    requirejs(['jquery', 'myslider' ],
      function ($, myslider) {
          $(document).ready(function(){

              // Custom Slider JS

          });
      });
  </script>
```

I have created popup manager module with custom jQuery popup you can take reference from here:

https://github.com/mageprince/Magento2-PopupManager

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:

IN your requiredjs-config.js put this code

File path:**Extension/your_Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {

    paths: {
        'helloWorld': 'Mageplaza_HelloWorld/js/jquery-bxslider-min' 
    }

};
```

Step-2:**Extension/your_Modul/view/frontend/templates/post.phtml**

Put below code in these location

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $block->getViewFileUrl('Mageplaza_HelloWorld::css/jquery.bxslider.css')?>">
    <div>
    <ul class="posts bxslider" >  
                        <li class="post">
 <img src=""/>
 <img src=""/>
 <img src=""/>
 <img src=""/>
                    </li>
         <?php  } ?> 
    </ul>
    </div>
```

put below code in these location

step-3:Extension/your_Module/view/frontend/web/css/jquery.bxslider.css

```
.bx-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto 60px;
  padding: 0;
  *zoom: 1;
  -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
  touch-action: pan-y;
}
.bx-wrapper img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  width:100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.bxslider {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul.bxslider {
  list-style: none;
}
.bx-viewport {
  /*fix other elements on the page moving (on Chrome)*/
  -webkit-transform: translatez(0);
}
/** THEME
===================================*/
.bx-wrapper {
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  background: #fff;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-pager,
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -30px;
  width: 100%;
}
/* LOADER */
.bx-wrapper .bx-loading {
  min-height: 50px;
  background: url('images/bx_loader.gif') center center no-repeat #ffffff;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2000;
}
/* PAGER */
.bx-wrapper .bx-pager {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: .85em;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #666;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a {
  background: #666;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  display: block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  outline: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a:hover,
.bx-wrapper .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a.active,
.bx-wrapper .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a:focus {
  background: #000;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-pager-item,
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-controls-auto-item {
  display: inline-block;
  *zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-pager-item {
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
}
/* DIRECTION CONTROLS (NEXT / PREV) */
.bx-wrapper .bx-prev {
  left: 10px;
  background: url('images/controls.png') no-repeat 0 -32px;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-prev:hover,
.bx-wrapper .bx-prev:focus {
  background-position: 0 0;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-next {
  right: 10px;
  background: url('images/controls.png') no-repeat -43px -32px;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-next:hover,
.bx-wrapper .bx-next:focus {
  background-position: -43px 0;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-direction a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -16px;
  outline: 0;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  z-index: 9999;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-direction a.disabled {
  display: none;
}
/* AUTO CONTROLS (START / STOP) */
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto {
  text-align: center;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-start {
  display: block;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 11px;
  outline: 0;
  background: url('images/controls.png') -86px -11px no-repeat;
  margin: 0 3px;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-start:hover,
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-start.active,
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-start:focus {
  background-position: -86px 0;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-stop {
  display: block;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  width: 9px;
  height: 11px;
  outline: 0;
  background: url('images/controls.png') -86px -44px no-repeat;
  margin: 0 3px;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-stop:hover,
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-stop.active,
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-stop:focus {
  background-position: -86px -33px;
}
/* PAGER WITH AUTO-CONTROLS HYBRID LAYOUT */
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls.bx-has-controls-auto.bx-has-pager .bx-pager {
  /*text-align: left;
  width: 80%;*/
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls.bx-has-controls-auto.bx-has-pager .bx-controls-auto {
  right: 0;
  width: 35px;
}
/* IMAGE CAPTIONS */
.bx-wrapper .bx-caption {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #666;
  background: rgba(80, 80, 80, 0.75);
  width: 100%;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-caption span {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Arial;
  display: block;
  font-size: .85em;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Put images in these location

**file path::Extension/your_Module/view/frontend/web/css/images**

Comment: Your answer is incomplete and will not work.